# C# and Java DES Encryption value are not identical

Tags: c#, java, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt the same data using C# and Java. If the data is more than 7 bytes then Java and C#'s encrypted value are not identical.

- Input 1: **a**
  java output: *FrOzOp/2Io8=*
  C#   output: *FrOzOp/2Io8=*
- Input 2: **abc**
  j : *H9A/ahl8K7I=*
  c#: *H9A/ahl8K7I=*
- Input 3: **aaaaaaaa**  (**Problem**)
  j : *Gxl7e0aWPd7j6l7uIEuMxA==*
  c#: *Gxl7e0aWPd7sf1xR6hK4VQ==*

Here is the implementation of C# and Java methods.
C# code:

```
public String saltTxt = "12345678";
public String Encrypt(String txt)
{
        byte[] data = Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt));
        
        DESCryptoServiceProvider alg = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        alg.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltTxt.ToCharArray(), 0, cprovider.KeySize / 8);
        alg.IV = new byte[8];

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream stem = new CryptoStream( ms, cprovider.CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        stem.Write(txt, 0, txt.Length);
        stem.FlushFinalBlock();

        data = ms.ToArray();
        
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
 }
```

Java Code:

```
public String saltTxt = "12345678";
public String Encrypt(String str) {
    try {
        KeySpec myKey = new DESKeySpec(saltTxt.getBytes("UTF8"));
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(myKey);
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF8");

        byte[] crypt = ecipher.doFinal(data);
        
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(crypt);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any idea why it's not working as expected?

Comment: Sounds like a padding problem. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx

Comment: The important thing is that roundtripping between the two should work. Does it?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it is padding problem. what is the default padding mechanism of java? 
if i specify `DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` in java part then both value are getting identical.

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul: So doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: yes, problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was in `mode` of encryption.

> SunJCE provider uses **`ECB`** as the default mode, and **`PKCS5Padding`** as the default padding scheme for DES, DES-EDE and Blowfish ciphers. ([JCA Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#CoreClasses))

and

> In `.Net`, The default operation  mode for the symmetric algorithm is **`CipherMode.CBC`** and default padding is **`PaddingMode.PKCS7`**. ([msdn..SymmetricAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode.aspx))

The following changes resolve the problem.

```
// in C# 
DESCryptoServiceProvider alg = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;  // specified
```

or

```
// in java
chiper = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

don't change in both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing ISO 10126 padding, which appends random bytes to the plaintext to fill it up t oa multiple of the block size.
This behavior is by design.

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul: Not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The code (Java/Android) bellow worke for me.
I used the same approach on C#.

```
public static String Cripto(String Password)
{
    String PasswordCripto = "";
    try
    {
        String encryptionKey = "anyEncryptionString";
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        messageDigest.update(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, encryptionKey.length());
        byte[] encryptionKeyBytes = messageDigest.digest();

        SecretKeySpec Key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKeyBytes,"DESede");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(Password.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        PasswordCripto = new String(Base64.encode(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");
    } catch(Exception e) { }
    return PasswordCripto ;
}
```