# Why android cannot ? DES mp4 encryption decryption success in desktop but failed an Android

Tags: android, encryption, des

I would like to implement a module for mp4 file encryption and decryption using DES .

It succeeds and decrypted file can play identically to the original sound track in desktop application but cannot in Android ? why ?

The below is my code
(Module)

```
private static final String key = "v@!#1SF5~6A5XZE3";

   public static void encrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void decrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {

    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); 

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        doCopy(cis, os);
    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        doCopy(is, cos);
    }
}

       public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
int numBytes;
while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
}
os.flush();
os.close();
is.close();
```

}

Application (Encryption) :

```
stopService(new Intent(AlaramScheduleActivity.this, RecordService.class));
        File instanceRecordDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Test");
        if(instanceRecordDirectory.exists()){       
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(instanceRecordDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +   "test.mp4");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(instanceRecordDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +   "etest.mp4");
            AESClientEncodeDecode.encrypt(fis, fos);
        }
```

Application (Decrpytion):

```
File instanceRecordDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Test");
    File decryptF = null;
    if(instanceRecordDirectory.exists()){

        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(instanceRecordDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +   "etest.mp4");
        FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(instanceRecordDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +   "dtest.mp4");
        AESClientEncodeDecode.decrypt(fis2, fos2);

    }

    decryptF = new File(instanceRecordDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +   "dtest.mp4");
    if(decryptF.exists()){          
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(decryptF), "audio/*");  
        startActivity(intent);          
    }else{
        toast("Recordings does not exists");
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894722/c-sharp-and-java-des-encryption-value-are-not-identical

Comment: I don't understand what this relates to my work. I have got correct algorithms to do so

Comment: Thought that maybe padding might be your issue as you are using a non-padded type on both sides.

Comment: Resolved , encryption process should not be immediately started after stopping the Service