# DES encryption in java and .net different result

Tags: java, .net

guys, this is my first time touch the DES encryption ,I hope my .net code and java code could create same encryption result by using my own key.I tried many code,but still confuse ,anyone can help me ?Is the encryption  mode problem?

This is my .net code

```
        byte[] byKey = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678");
        byte[] byIV = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678");


        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
   //     int i = cryptoProvider.KeySize;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cst = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(byKey, byIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cst);
        sw.Write(data);
        sw.Flush();
        cst.FlushFinalBlock();
        sw.Flush();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
```

This is my java code

`

```
String  epsKey ="12345678";
    String  str ="hcs";
DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(epsKey.getBytes());
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
//ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF8"));
String encryptedString = new BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

System.out.println(encryptedString);
```

`

Comment: Yes, the encryption mode is the problem. By default .NET use `CBC` while java on the other hand use `ECB`. See this similiar question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894722/c-sharp-and-java-des-encryption-value-are-not-identical